# Angular2 Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Tags: angular, data-binding

Hi I'm trying to get data(that has been extracted after ngFor) from html using viewChildren and elementRef but I'm getting

```
Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? I am also using `ngAfterViewInit`

These are my code (html)

```
<div id="tutor-price" #myDiv (click)="passCharge(r.value['charge'])"><span id="month">8 Times a month</span> <span id="price"> {{r.value['charge']}} </span></div>
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'


@ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   let el: HTMLElement = this.myDiv.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
   el.click();
 }
```

by doing above, I'd like to toggle click event automatically when the component is done loading.

But I'm getting error.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: just change `el.click();` to `el.click` in your code.It will work perfecft.

Comment: Did you implement AfterViewInit ? `class XXX implements OnInit, AfterViewInit`

Comment: (By the way, it looks a lot like the code I provided this morning, is it the case ?)

Answer (score 2):

You assign the template variable to a normal `HTMLElement` and not to a component tag, this will make the `myDiv` field property a `HTMLElement` and not an `ElementRef`:

```
@ViewChild('myDiv') 
myDiv: HTMLDivElement;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   el.click();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use ViewChild variable after View has initialized, i.e. use -

```
ngAfterViewInit()
```